# System.IO.FileNotFoundException error when running Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, native, windows-phone

I have a Windows Runtime Component that uses some native libraries ([the PJSIP library](http://www.pjsip.org/)). This component is used in a Windows Phone 8 Application and when I try to invoke a function from the native component I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in TestingApp.DLL but was not handled in user code
```

with the Source (at Exception Details) in mscorlib.

Can anyone point out what may be causing this error and how can I find out what is missing actually? When I try to put a breakpoint in my Windows Runtime Component, at runtime, the breakpoint appears as disabled.

Regards,
Tamas

Comment: Nope. At the time I was working on, the PJSIP library could not be used for Windows Phone 8 devices. I don't know how is supported now however

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing `dll` to the project (like adding a new file) and mark it as content. Then reference the dll from this location. This may resolve your problem.

I guess it is not working as it is not being deployed within your application.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what exactly is missing. The TestingApp.DLL is my Windows Phone 8 Application. I have added PJSIPCore.dll (which is my Windows Runtime Component) to the application and marked as content, but I still get the same error at runtime.

Comment: you need to find the dlls which PJSIP is referencing.

Comment: I have added all the dlls that my PJSIP WinRT component is referencing as "Content" in my main application and I still get the same error.

Comment: Actually I have added all the .lib files that PJSIP is referencing. The PJSIP WinRT component is not referencing any dlls, only libs.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio, under the debug menu select 'Exceptions' then in the dialogue that appears enable 'Thrown' for 'Common language runtime exceptions'

Then re-run your application,  Visual Studio should break now at the line in the code that is causing the Null Exception.

Comment: I don't get a null exception. I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException error. My code breaks when I want from the WP8 App to create an object that is defined in my Win RT component (that calls other native libraries). I've added another simple WinRT component and works ok with that one. My guess is that somehow the WinRT is calling other native libs that aren't found and this error is somehow propagated at my WP8 app. I cannot put a breakpoint into my "troublesome" WinRT at the constructor for the class I need.

Comment: Can you remake your WinRT component as a portable class?

Comment: How can I do that? And how will it help?

Comment: there is a good read on the subject here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you reference a native library, double-check if you also reference C++ Runtime. Under your project in Solution Explorer, right-click References > Add Reference... Go to Extensions and check Visual C++ Runtime Package.

Answer (score 0):

Check the library file you linked, it should be a import library for DLL file.

An import library (.lib) file contains information the linker needs to resolve external references to exported DLL functions, so the system can locate the specified DLL and exported DLL functions at run time.

When app start it find DLL files according to the import library, but there is no such DLL files, so C# throw a FileNotFoundException. Make sure link to a static library